# Want to remove Boostrap mobile Nav Button Border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my first post. My website (zidanmarketing.com) is using bootstrap, When the mobile button is active there is a blue border that I am unable to remove. How do I resolve this?

```
.navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-toggle:active,
.navbar-toggle:focus
{
background:none !important;
border-color:none !important;
}
```

Comment: it's called "outline". use css to remove it

Answer (score 9):

```
.navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

For targeting 767px and below, usually where the mobile button triggers try this.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-toggle {
      border: none;
      outline: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: The class name has been updated to `.navbar-toggler` in Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 2):

try using  `outline: 0;`

The blue outline is a default on pressed buttons on chrome and some other browsers. Outline 0 should have that fixed!

Comment: outline:none in Chrome Mac v51 did not work for me, but outline: 0 did the job!

Answer (score 1):

[Customizing Bootstrap](https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/)

Make sure when customizing Bootstrap CSS to link your custom style sheet after the bootstrap link.